# Tektronix MSO4104B oscilloscope SCPI command to add a measurement

Tags: oscilloscope

I have searched the programmer's manual in vain.

I can configure measurements if already on-screen but cannot figure how to add measurements if not present.

Does anyone know the correct command?

Comment: Have you read [this document](https://download.tek.com/manual/MDO4000-MSO4000B-and-DPO4000B-Oscilloscope-Programmer-Manual.pdf) (the very first hit using your question title)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The measurements are always there behind the scenes. You can control whether they are displayed on the screen using for example:

```
MEASUrement:MEAS<x>:STATE ON|OFF
```

And you can configure the measurements using, for example:

```
MEASUrement:MEAS<x>:TYPe FREQuency
MEASUrement:MEAS<x>:SOUrce CH2
MEASUrement:MEAS<x>:SOUrce2 CH1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Tek scope expert and probably shouldn't comment since I work for Keysight (lol), but it seems there's two options. Option 1 is to grab a measurement result for a measurement that's already been made/already on screen, and the other option is to take a new measurement. From page 64:

"
To obtain measurement results, use the MEASUrement:MEAS:VALue?
query for displayed results or the MEASUrement:IMMed:VALue? query for
immediate measurements.
"

I suspect you're trying the first option, when you should be looking for the IMMed value instead?